# How to retrieve the dependencies when retrieving a package via sfdx?

Tags: salesforcedx

Let's say I have a scratch org that has 5 packages (1 to 5).

I wish to retrieve the meta-data from the 3rd package, so I use the mdapi:retrieve command to retrieve the meta-data from the 3rd package.

I unzip the contents in the directory and I see the meta-data from the 3rd package only there (which is good).

However, I also want to retrieve the sfdx-project.json file (or at least, the meta-data that tells me the dependencies of the 3rd package). For example, package 3 is dependent on package 1 and package 2.

***QUESTION:*** Is there a command to target a package and return the "dependencies" parameter from the sfdx-project.json file? Ideally, I'd see something like this:

```
        "dependencies": [
            {
                "package": "Package1",
                "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
            },
            {
                "package": "Package2",
                "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this can help identify the dependencies from a particular package.

This [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_subscriberpackageversion.htm) is also helpful.

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -u [insert either org alias or username alias] -t -q "SELECT Dependencies FROM SubscriberPackageVersion WHERE id='04tXXXXXX' and InstallationKey='ABC'" --json | grep subscriberPackageVersionId
```