# How can I find the dependent packages of a package version?

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, package-dependency

Given that I have two packages (packageA, packageB) and packageA depends on packageB, I would like that when I release a new version of packageB, I can automatically upgrade the package version Id of packageA (and all other upstream repositories/packages).

So far I can't find a way to determine the dependent packages of a package version, only the opposite. So if I query [SubscriberPackageVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_subscriberpackageversion.htm) object I get the dependencies, how can I find the dependents of a packageVersion?

(This question is basically the opposite of [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271919/how-to-retrieve-the-dependencies-when-retrieving-a-package-via-sfdx))

Comment: By changing A to depend on the latest version of B you basically say it is no longer compatible with the older version of B. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: @PhilW thanks for your comment, yeah I basically want to automatically bump the version of packageB in packageA once there's a new version of packageB released

Comment: Given that the source of truth is your git repo, you need to write scripting that deals with this in your git repo, across your various projects. Note that Salesforce recommend the use of a "mono repo" to address modular 2GPs, and adopting this approach would clearly simplify your dependency management, since it would all be there in one place.